# Summing rows at a fixed distance in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have the following matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `(m*d)x2`

```
A=[1 1; 
   3 2; 
   8 3;
  -----
   9 1;
   2 2;
   5 3;
  -----
   6 1;
   1 2;
   4 3;
  -----
   8 1;
   1 2;
   5 3];
```

Hence `m=max(A(:,2))=3` and `d=4` is the number of submatrices in `A` of dimension `mx2`. The second column is always composed by integers always disposed in a cyclical.

I want to obtain the vector `B` of dimension `mx1` by summing the elements of `A(:,1)` associated with the same integer of the second column without using loops, i.e.

```
B=[1+9+6+8;
  -------
   3+2+1+1;
  -------
   8+5+4+5];
```

Could you help me?

Comment: It the second column always cyclical (1 2 3 1 2 3...)? Or could it be something like 1 3 2 3 1 2...? Is it always integers?

Comment: Always cyclical, always integers. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In increasing order of generality:

- If the second column is always cyclical: [`reshape`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`sum`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html):

  ```
  result = sum(reshape(A(:,1), m, []), 2);
  ```
- If the second column consists of integers: use [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

  ```
  result = accumarray(A(:,2), A(:,1));
  ```
- In the most general case, you need [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) before `accumarray`:

  ```
  [~, ~, u] = unique(A(:,2));
  result = accumarray(u, A(:,1));
  ```